# algorithm2e and xeCJK cause TeX capacity exceeded on texlive2016

Tags: xetex, algorithm2e, xecjk

My document cannot be compiled after I updated texlive on my Mac to version 2016. It works fine on texlive 2013.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[vlined,linesnumbered,noend,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
  hello
\end{document}
```

The output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty)
********************************************************
Package `algorithm2e' Release 5.1 -- october 19 2015 --
- algorithm2e-announce@lirmm.fr mailing list for announcement about releases
- algorithm2e-discussion@lirmm.fr mailing list for discussion about package
subscribe by emailing sympa@lirmm.fr with 'subscribe <list> <firstname name>'
- Author: Christophe Fiorio (christophe.fiorio@umontpellier.fr)
********************************************************
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.st
y) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].
<argument> ..._xeCJK_begin_int =\l__xeCJK_tmp_int
                                                  \int_incr:N \l__xeCJK_begi...
l.642 \xeCJKResetCharClass

No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I have tried to enlarge the save size but it didn't work. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a problem in line 1061 of `algorithm2e.sty`, that reads

```
\newboolean{algocf@displaygroupmarkers}{\setboolean{algocf@displaygroupmarkers}{false}
```

but the `{` brace before `\setboolean` is wrong (and unbalanced).

This gets mostly unnoticed, just causing a warning in the log file; in the case of `xeCJK`, the tons of assignments it does are performed in the group that has been opened causing exhaustion of memory.

The remedy, until the developer fixes the issue (already reported months ago), is to make a copy of the file and remove the wrong `{` and placing it in the “personal” TeX tree or in the same folder as the main file.

Comment: I reported this bug to the package author on Nov 24, 2015. I've resent it with a link to this post.

Comment: @Werner I reported it, too. And went the hard way: I removed the wrong brace in the distributed file. Don't tell anyone. 